# android firebase saving app setting

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing ad Android app, using Firebase as db.

In this app there's the possibility to add buttons in the main activity.
I need to save this information in the db so that if a user adds a button, when he close the app and reopen it, he founds the button added and working.

I need to save it on the local db and on the online db 'cause a user could access the app from another device (but with the same user/pass) and he need to find the buttons added.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Edit:
I use this method to add the buttons in the activity

```
public void addNewUnity(String unityType, String unityName) {
    Button btnUnity = new Button(this);
    btnUnity.setText(unityName + " " + unityType);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivityUnityLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(btnUnity, lp);

    //TODO Saving button (with text) in the db
}
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't store the data anywhere. To find out how to store in the Firebase Database, read the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Yeah, I know. I shared the code I use to create the button and to add it to the activity. What I need to know is how I can save the button data in the db (and how I can retrieve them), I'll read the documentation you linked, thanks.

Comment: Save the values of `unityType` and `unityName` in the db. When you create the activity, check for those values and add the button if they're present in the db.